# MySQL: SELECT existing and non-existing IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, left-join

The table may look like this:

```
id | label
----------
 1 | red
 3 | green
 5 | blue
```

Now, there’s a given set of IDs, which have to be compared against the DB. Let’s say `(3, 4, 5)`.

I’m looking for a SELECT statement that returns the existing IDs including the label and the non-existing with label = null.

So given `(3, 4, 5)` I’m looking for this result

```
id | label
----------
 3 | green
 4 | NULL
 5 | blue
```

How can I do this in **MySQL/MariaDB**?

In PostgreSQL it would be `SELECT FROM (VALUES (3), (4), (5)) t(id)` combined with a left join with the table. However, I didn’t find an alternative for MySQL.

Comment: Where does the "given set if IDs" come from? Is it a result of another query? If so, you can just use a join to get your result. If it is from somewhere else, you are gonna need to use unions or subqueries to get your desired result

Comment: @RisingSun The set is supplied externally via the user and not inside the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the question was tagged with [mariadb](/questions/tagged/mariadb), note that it does support `VALUES`. [Checked](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4fb00320c673ccef0f2d3303e1f80785) on MariaDB 10.3:

```
WITH u(id) AS (VALUES (3), (4), (5))
  SELECT u.id, t.label
  FROM u LEFT JOIN t ON u.id = t.id;
```

| id | label |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | green |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | blue |

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-query as an inline-view, using `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
            SELECT 3 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT 4
  UNION ALL SELECT 5
)
  AS params
LEFT JOIN
  some_table
    ON some_table.id = params.id
```

Or fall back on having robust dimension tables.

For example, a user may or may not have an entry in a `favourite_fruit` table, but the `fruit` table can be relied upon to be fully populated.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  user
CROSS JOIN
  fruit
LEFT JOIN
  favourite_fruit
    ON  favourite_fruit.user_id  = user.id
    AND favourite_fruit.fruit_id = fruit.id
WHERE
      user.id  IN (1,2,3)
  AND fruit.id IN (3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySql 8.0+ you can do the same with the [ROW() constructor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html):

```
SELECT c.id, t.label
FROM ((VALUES ROW(3), ROW(4), ROW(5))) c(id) 
LEFT JOIN tablename t 
ON t.id = c.id;
```

Or with a CTE:

```
WITH cte(id) AS (VALUES ROW(3), ROW(4), ROW(5))
SELECT c.id, t.label
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN tablename t 
ON t.id = c.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=472202054dc34183719a72c5c76a29cd).